# C# Safely Navigate to Registry Path

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

Basically I need to create a path to:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\myDomain\Subdomain

And create a DWORD named * (an asterisk) with the value of 2
I get an error during run time in the console and it doesn't do anything.

I assume this is because myDomain\Subdomain doesn't exist.  Here is my code:

```
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\ZoneMap\\Domains\\google.com\\sites", true);
myKey.SetValue("*", "2", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
myKey.Close();
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in app.exe @DWright

Answer (score 0):

CurrentUser returns a RegistryKey.  You want to call CreateSubKey on that.  Like this, I think:

```
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\ZoneMap\\Domains\\google.com\\sites",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  I was simply overcomplicating something I had tried earlier, solution is as follows:

```
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\ZoneMap\\Domains\\google.com\\sites");
        myKey.SetValue("*", "2", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        myKey.Close();
```